# Get Combo Box selected item from different module

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am very new to Python and am using this project to learn and hopefully it will of use in a real-world situation.  The script was getting too long, and I was having trouble understanding what all was going on, so I split the code to different modules.
I moved all the MySQL database functions queries, insert, delete to a separate module. I have about 35 widgets including labels, entry, and a combo box which I moved to another module: my_win. The module will set up the windows screen and populate the combo box and includes the following to capture the selected item from the combo box.

```
    def callback(event):
        win_cb = event.widget.get()
        print(win_cb)

    cb = ttk.Combobox(tab1, width=25)
    cb.grid(row=1, column=3)
    cb.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callback)
```

In the my_main module I import both modules. And everything works as expected: all the db calls work and the screen is displayed.
My question is how do I know from my_main what item was selected in the combo box in my_win? When a item is selected win_cb is printed, but how do I get the selected value into my_main. Also, how do I know when an item is selected.

Thanks for any guidance.
John

Comment: Tricky. Based on what you are trying to explain, you import a module using all tkinter code. This probably includes creating a main window and the also the main event loop. This code runs on import as a separate program: the main program. All other actions should be performed from within this main program. My suggestion would be to make the tkinter module the main one, and work from there.

Comment: Try moving `callback()` and `cb.bind(...)` into `my_main`.